# Possible to manage ECS cluster using Distributed Spinnaker Setup?

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-eks, cicd, spinnaker-halyard

I want do a Distribution installation for Spinnaker and I am aware that, it can be achived only through kubernetes. But, all my application micro-services are running in AWS ECS cluster. So I am wondering, is it possible to install Spinnaker as a distribution setup in AWS EKS and use it to manage all my services which are running in AWS ECS cluster.

If yes, is it the recommended way? or there are other better methods available?

==================

Installed Halyard in a Ubuntu Virtual Machine

Cloud Provider: AWS

Choose environment: Distributed installation

External Storage: S3

Deployed Spinnake in K8 cluster as distributed setup.

==================

Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Yes, this is possible. After spinnaker is deployed (in any manner) just use the [AWS provider](https://spinnaker.io/docs/setup/install/providers/aws/). What have you tried? Do you have a specific problem you're running into?